# Find retention policies where items get deleted or moved to recycle bin using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, retention

Is there a way to use PowerShell to look through SP2010 to produce a report listing all the locations a retention policy is set that has the property to either delete the item or move items to recycle bin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List policy xml is stored in the RetentionPolicy.xml file in the root folder of the list (Forms/RetentionPolicy.Xml). An idea, iterating lists and reading RetentionPolicy.xml file for the list, check the action.

You can read the following thread to learn how to get RetentionPolicy.xml file:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3a7323f6-a3fd-4e2b-9c67-27a1fc18c1c4/how-to-get-sharepoint-list-retention-policy-description?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious